# How to use symfony2 DQL query to fill a drop down

Tags: symfony

```
->add('supervisor','entity', array(
          'class' => 'AdminBundle:Managers',
          'expanded' => false,
          'multiple' => false,
            )
```

So I want the class property to take this query:

```
select e.firstname,e.middlename,e.lastname from employee e, user u where e.staffid=u.staffid and  u.role=3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom query in entity field type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456298/custom-query-in-entity-field-type)

Comment: I think query_builder allow only the symfony2 query builder notation but does it allow DQL queries which is sql like query                                                                    
thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Use the query_builder option to create a custom query that will be used when fetching the drop-down options. Here you can add joins and conditions to create the custom query.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: I think query_builder allow only the symfony2 query builder notation but does it allow DQL queries which is sql like query